# unable to apply learned model to test data in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, prediction, kaggle

I am using the `Titanic` dataset from Kaggle and want to learn a simple logistic regression model.

I read in the train and test data and both `train$Survived`, `train$Sex`, `test$Survived` and `test$Sex` are factors.

I would like to perform a very simple logistic regression with Sex being the only independent variable.

```
fit <- glm(formula = Survived ~ Sex, family = binomial)
```

It seems to look okay to me:

```
> fit

Call:  glm(formula = Survived ~ Sex, family = binomial)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      Sexmale  
      1.057       -2.514  

Degrees of Freedom: 890 Total (i.e. Null);  889 Residual
Null Deviance:      1187 
Residual Deviance: 917.8    AIC: 921.8
```

Problem is, I am unable to apply this learned model to the test data. When I do the following:

```
predict(fit, train$Sex)
```

I get a vector with 891 values which is the amount of training examples in the training set.

I can't seem to find any information on how to do this right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your `fit` code, where is the data?`predict(fit, newdata = test)` will do the work.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! This is not mentioned by documentation for predict and only under predict.glm... Predict seems to be outputting floats though and not "labels" that were originally used to learn the model. Is there any way I can correct this? (turns out my train$Survived is of type integer... let me try with factors...) no luck, still floats as output...

Comment: yes, you have to use `predict.glm` for that. I missed `.glm`. Sorry for that.

Comment: You could use `predict.glm(..., type = "response")`. Like that, you end up with probabilities indicating whether your record is most likely female (high values) or male (low values).

Comment: Thank you, this is much nicer. Still, would be really neat if there was a way of outputting the predicted category. Guess can be quite useful for logistic regression where several labels are possible

Comment: Don't know whether there's a direct solution, but `as.factor(ifelse(predict(fit, newdata = df.test, type = "response") >= .5, "female", "male"))` works for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting an answer to correct a couple points that seem to have gotten confused. There really is no `predict`-function as such. That is what is meant where the help page says "predict" is a "generic function". Sometimes generic functions do have a `fun.default` method, but in the case of `predict.*`, there is no default method. So dispatch is on the basis of the class of the first argument. There will be separate help pages for each method and the help page for "predict" lists several. Package authors need to write their own predict methods for new classes.

Logistic regression predates the machine learning paradigm, so expecting it to "predict classes" is somewhat unrealistic. Even the fact that you can get a "response" prediction is a gift over what the software would have provided 30 years ago when some of us were taking our regression classes. One needs to understand that probabilities are generally not 0 or 1 but rather something in between. If the user wants to set a threshold and determine how many cases exceed the threshold then that is an analyst decision and the analysts need to make any transformations to categories they deem worthwhile.

Executing: `predict(fit, train$Sex)` would be expected to give a result that was as long as there were values from the training set, so I'm guessing that you perhaps meant to try `predict(fit, test$Sex)` and were disappointed. If that's the case then it should have been: `predict(fit, list(Sex=test$Sex) )`. R needs the argument to be a value that can be coerced to a dataframe, so a named list of values is a minimum requirement for `predict`-ors.

If `predict.glm` gets a malformed argument to the second argument, `newdata`, it falls back on the original data argument and uses the linear predictors that are retained in the model object.